# How to make a thin slice of an image span from the top of a section to the bottom of the section?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do something as follows:

[image]

Here is my following code:

```css
.section-projects {
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
}

.project-showcase li {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    display: block;
    float:left;
    width:50%
}

.project-photo {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.project-photo img {
    
    opacity: 0.7;
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    transform: scale(1.15);
    transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
}

.project-photo img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.03);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-projects">
            <ul class="project-showcase">
                <li>
                    <figure class="project-photo">
                        <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a>
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure class="project-photo">
                        <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a>
                    </figure>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
```

I have achieved the effect I want, but how do I crop the images so that they appear as thin slices instead of taking up the entire screen? I cant seem to figure out how to do this.

Furthermore, how do I add text over these images?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I have inserted the linked image, but it will be nicer if you can actually prepare a more illustrative example. Also, good start with the code snippet: however, the images in your code is not loading at all. I suggest using dummy images, such as those from https://placeholder.com/, to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I inserted some placeholder images.
Do you know how I could crop them to make them thinner vertically?